# PHP Get end string on url between / and /

Tags: php

I need to get the last string content of the url between / and /

For example:

```
http://mydomain.com/get_this/

or

http://mydomain.com/lists/get_this/
```

I need to get where get_this is in the url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Get last word of url returning blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090034/php-get-last-word-of-url-returning-blank) - Why are you duplicating the questions?????

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) removes the trailing slash, [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) finds the last occurrence of `/` (after it's trimmed), and [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) gets all content after the last occurrence of `/`.

```
$url = trim($url, '/');
echo substr($url, strrpos($url, '/')+1);
```

<sup>[View output](http://codepad.org/QLHvhhiY)</sup>

---

Even better, you can just use [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php), like hakre suggested:

```
echo basename($url);
```

<sup>[View output](http://codepad.org/JonOCPIR)</sup>

Comment: +1 from me too, though it should be noted that this will return last segment of the uri, even if there was no trailing slash ;) not sure if this was the intention

Comment: @Jeroen: psst, it's just `basename($url);` ;)

Comment: @Jeroen: No, just one line: `echo basename($url);` - that's all. basename does all the work. that's it. that's what it is for. that's what it has been made for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there *always* is a trailing slash:

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$get_this = $parts[count($parts)-2]; // -2 since there will be an empty array element due to the trailing slash
```

If not:

```
$url = trim($url, '/'); // If there is a trailing slash in this URL instance get rid of it so we're always sure the last part is where we expect it
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$get_this = $parts[count($parts)-1];
```

Comment: Someone went on a downvoting spree

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
<?php
$subject = "http://mydomain.com/lists/get_this/";
$pattern = '/\/([^\/]*)\/$/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and `explode()`:

```
<?php

$url = "http://mydomain.com/lists/get_this/";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path_array = array_filter(explode('/', $path));
$last_path = $path_array[count($path_array) - 1];

echo $last_path;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
preg_match("/http:\/\/([a-z0-9\.]+)\/(.+)\/(.*)\/?/", $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```