# PHP Get last word of url returning blank

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Get end string on url between / and /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075301/php-get-end-string-on-url-between-and)

I have this code to get the last part of the url between / and / at the end.

The url is:

```
http://mydomain.com/category/mobile/
```

I need to retrieve "mobile" from it.

The code i'm using is:

```
$url = trim($url, '/');

//Put it in a variable
$the_category = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/'));

//whats in it?
echo $the_category;
```

The above returns nothing ... any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code and it prints `/mobile`

Comment: I just trie this out by setting $url = "http://mydomain.com/category/mobile/" and it worked fine. Returned /mobile as expected.

Comment: Working http://codepad.org/f5dhMGAw

Comment: how are you assigning `$url` initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explode an array using "/" as the delimiter and then get the last value of the array, like so:

```
<?
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url = trim($url, '/');

$array = explode('/',$url);

$the_category = end($array);

//what's in it?
echo $the_category;
?>
```

Comment: Ultimately how is this different from what he was doing? He's parsing the position of the last forward-slash in the string.. you're doing the same except exploding out each element into a new (unused) variable just to pop the end off. Your way probably has a higher memory footprint because of the array. Both these methods are pretty sloppy methods of parsing request params.

Comment: His included the forward slash so it returned "/mobile" instead of "mobile", but an array is good to have in case there are subcategories contained within the URI that he might need to use also.  Plus he said his wasn't working (to be fair I didn't test it) and this one does.

Comment: This works with the hardcoded url string...how do I get $url to get my actual url instead of the hardcoded string?

Comment: @Satch3000 What? You tell us where `$url` comes from.

Comment: Ahh, use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].  I'll edit the code for ya

Comment: -1: why not use `basename()`? that's what it's there for. Also, recommended not to use short-style PHP tags -- ie use `<?php` instead of just `<?`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$the_category = basename($url);
```

Comment: +1: yep. if you're going to use PHP, you may as well use the utility functions it provides rather than rewriting them yourself.